# any api to get record count from ResultSet returned from executeQuery() MariaDB using mariadb-connector-cpp?

Tags: c++, mariadb, mariadb-connector-cpp

We are executing queries in MariaDB from C++ code using mariadb-connector-cpp.

```
string query = "select ID,Name,Res from table_name";
std::unique_ptr<sql::Statement> stmnt(conn->createStatement());
sql::ResultSet *res = stmnt->executeQuery(query);
```

Is there any way or api to get the number of rows fetched from executeQuery() call? while loop can be used to get the records count, but we want to take action based on the records count without going over loop.

Please share if any api exposed from mariadb-connector-cpp.

Comment: try https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mysql_stmt_affected_rows/

Comment: @nbk being a select you may mean [mysql_stmt_num_rows](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mysql_stmt_num_rows/).

Comment: @danblack A note in mysql_stmt_num_rows page, 'If you use mysql_stmt_store_result(), mysql_stmt_num_rows() may be called immediately.' Does this mean, mysql_stmt_num_rows can be used only if store_result() is called before?

Comment: Not sure, it does need to be better explained. But its the connector-c and you where using connector-cpp so I think the answer below still holds as the right answer for connector-cpp.

Answer (score 2):

Connector/C++ is implementing JDBC-like interface. For main functionality it is pretty safe to refer to JDBC specs, given the lack of C/C++ documentation.

But not in this case :) danblack has given the correct answer - ResultSet::rowsCount() returns number of rows in the resultset if possible. JDBC doesn't have this method, and this is one of small extensions implemented in the C/C++. If a resultset is being streamed, then you won't get the total number of rows. It's only possible when the whole resultset has been cached on the client.

mysql_stmt_store_result() and mysql_stmt_num_rows(), and also mysql_store_result() with mysql_num_rows can be added to this row, that have been mentioned by commenters here are from C API, i.e. for Connector/C and obviously cannot be used with C/C++

Answer (score 1):

It is accessible with `res->rowsCount()`

ref: [source test case](https://github.com/mariadb-corporation/mariadb-connector-cpp/blob/b09555de99ed4b1d054a88ff85acbae996bce1d1/test/test_common.cpp#L887-L888)

Comment: Worked fine with smaller data (num rows fetched is 400 and data size is ~50,000 bytes). On a larger data set (2000 rows and data size 20,00,000bytes), Do we need to call mysql_stmt_store_result() before fetching rowsCount()?

Comment: To determine the correct amount of rows you always have to store result before (or fetch all rows). When using unbuffered results, the only way to get the exact number is to execute an additional sql statement (SELECT COUNT()).